# Subtracting DataFrames by a single ID column - duplicate columns behave differently

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compare two DataFrames with the same schema (in Spark 1.6.0, using Scala) to determine which rows in the newer table have been added (i.e. are not present in the older table).

I need to do this *by ID* (i.e. examining a single column, not the whole row, to see what is new). Some rows may have changed between the versions, in that they have the same *id* in both versions, but the *other* columns have changed - I do not want these in the output, so I cannot simply subtract the two versions.

Based on various suggestions, I am doing a left-outer join on the chosen ID column, then selecting rows with nulls in columns from the right side of the join (indicating that they were not present in the older version of the table):

```
def diffBy(field:String, newer:DataFrame, older:DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  newer.join(older, newer(field) === older(field), "left_outer")
       .select(older(field).isNull)
       // TODO just select the leftmost columns, removing the nulls
}
```

However, this does not work. (row 3 exists only in the newer version, so should be output):

```
scala> newer.show
+---+-------+
| id|  value|
+---+-------+
|  3|  three|
|  2|two-new|
+---+-------+

scala> older.show
+---+-------+
| id|  value|
+---+-------+
|  1|    one|
|  2|two-old|
+---+-------+

scala> diffBy("id", newer, older).show
+---+-----+---+-----+
| id|value| id|value|
+---+-----+---+-----+
+---+-----+---+-----+
```

The join is working as expected:

```
scala> val joined = newer.join(older, newer("id") === older("id"), "left_outer")
scala> joined.show
+---+-------+----+-------+
| id|  value|  id|  value|
+---+-------+----+-------+
|  2|two-new|   2|two-old|
|  3|  three|null|   null|
+---+-------+----+-------+
```

So the problem is in the selection of the column for filtering.

```
joined.where(older("id").isNull).show
+---+-----+---+-----+
| id|value| id|value|
+---+-----+---+-----+
+---+-----+---+-----+
```

Perhaps it is due to the duplicate `id` column names in the join? But if I use the `value` column (which is also duplicated) instead to detect nulls, it works as expected:

```
joined.where(older("value").isNull).show
+---+-----+----+-----+
| id|value|  id|value|
+---+-----+----+-----+
|  3|three|null| null|
+---+-----+----+-----+
```

What is going on here - and why is the behaviour different for `id` and `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem using a special spark join called "leftanti" . It is equivalent to minus (in Oracle PL SQL).

```
val joined = newer.join(older, newer("id") === older("id"), "leftanti")
```

This will only select columns from `newer`.

Comment: Excellent - just to note that this is available from Spark 2.0 onwards (I'm currently stuck on Spark 1.6, so can't use this until we migrate)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem, though not an explanation for why it occurs.

It seems to be necessary to create an alias in order to refer unambiguously to the rightmost `id` column, and then use a textual `WHERE` clause so that I can substitute in the qualified column name from the variable `field`:

```
newer.join(older.as("o"), newer(field) === older(field), "left_outer")
     .where(s"o.$field IS NULL")
```